how to show total at jmeter dashboard statictics report only show for total repeatation of transaction controller not sampler?
i have set at my user.properties jmeter using this
 jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.show_controllers_only=true

but when i show at my report

my report give total sampler hit as 42. but i only show total transaction controller repeatation around 1-2... and from this data only 12 data... i want to manipulate to show total at my dashboard for only calculate same like total of my transaction controller process... any idea for that ? or is there any possibility for to do that ?

As per documentation for the property:

Indicates whether only controller samples are displayed on graphs that support it.

I think you need to come up with a proper regular expression for the jmeter.reportgenerator.sample_filter property
More information:

Filtering Configuration
Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide

